# CSS dropdown menu with sub div

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am trying to create a nav bar. Each link has detailed sub-menu like, images text search form etc. I am trying to do something as shown in the image.

I have attached a Snippet of what i tried! but it's not what i expected.

HERE SAMPLE:[image]

```css
.menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none
}
ul.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #b0063a
}
ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border-right: 1px #b0063a dotted;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px
}
ul.menu ul li {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
ul.menu li:hover>ul {
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="ınfo">Info</a>
    <ul>
      <li>HERE is some images and etc.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What results were you expecting?

Comment: on sample gif there is result but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: the big block that shows below is a div that loads separate from the rest of the menu ie. its not defined in the same container as the menu links themselves

Comment: what if there are multiple links?

Comment: also if i did it seperate while i leave link dropdown doesn't shown.

Comment: guys any ideas?